# Report Wrong-Doing in Class

Tags: ethics

In my class, one of my colleagues plays games on computers for about 1 hour each day in class. What should I do? Should I report it to the teacher or should I take matters into my own hands?

Comment: This isn't cheating.  It may be annoying and against the rules, but cheating would be something where they submit academic work that isn't an accurate reflection of their own knowledge.

Comment: Why does this bother you, and in what sense is this “wrong-doing”?

Comment: Where did the colleagues sit? Do they sit in the front row? Back row? Did they turn on the audio volume loud? Why did it bother you?

Comment: @scaaahu YES, it bothers me. The rest of us are trying to study and he decides to play Roblox while we are working. Doesn't it bother you.

Comment: This is Academia SE not kindergarten SE

Answer (score 12):

Let him / her be : it's up to them.

Are you required to report it? If you are then do it but dispassionately and, if necessary, privately.

Whatever else, don't take matters into your own hands and don't get distracted - concentrate on the class for your own benefit. If necessary sit somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

You said in a comment that the student’s game-playing bothers you, and I think that that’s very reasonable - the classroom is not an appropriate place for people to play computer games in, which is an activity that could well distract the other students and hurt the learning environment. So yes, I think you would be within your rights to complain to the instructor. BUT - a couple of tips to keep in mind when you speak to the instructor:

1. Keep your tone as factual and neutral as possible. Do not accuse the student of “wrong-doing”, which to me sounds very judgmental and sanctimonious, or use similarly accusatory language; just state that his game-playing is distracting you and makes it difficult for you to focus on the material. That ought to be enough to get the teacher to act.
2. Do not talk about “taking matters into your own hands”. You may not realize it but that phrase carries a certain connotation of a threat of violence, and obviously creating an impression that that may be your intent is a very bad idea.

In general, your goal should be to get the student to stop playing games in class rather than to get him punished for “wrong-doing”; make sure that your motivation in complaining is pure and that you are not acting out of vindictiveness or malice. And keep in mind that there is always the option of having a quiet word with the student directly, pointing out that he is being inconsiderate of you and the other students in the class, and asking him to stop. That may be more awkward than going through the instructor, but probably will be a more mature way to resolve the situation. If that approach fails, you can still talk to the instructor after that.

Comment: I won't injure someone, but as I have administrative powers on my school computer network, I could repeatedly delete it from her computer.

Comment: That could be taken as an abuse of power...